# Split the data frame into two data frames based on the column name and sort the two data frames based on the column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to split the data frame into two data frames and I have a column name called 'product_type'. depends on the product type I need to split the main data frame and sort it based on another column name 'id'. the id should be matched.

```
My data frame:

product, id, product_type
car1, FY-2, forecast
car1, FY-3, forecast
car1, FY-1, forecast
car3, FY-3, reference
car2, FY-1, reference
car4, FY-2, reference

Expected Result:

df1:

product, id, product_type
car1, FY-2, forecast
car1, FY-3, forecast
car1, FY-1, forecast


df2:

product, id, product_type
car3, FY-2, reference
car2, FY-3, reference
car4, FY-1, reference

two data frames are sorted based on the id split based on the product_type.
```

Comment: `df1 = my_df[my_df['product_type'] == 'forecast'].sort_values('id')`

and similar for df2. The two df ids will be matched if there is both a reference and forecast row for each id

Comment: what kind of sorting are you talking about on the ID column?  Those don't appear to be sorted in any particular way.

Comment: id's in both the data frames should be matched by rows

Comment: How does `car3` suddenly have a new id `FY-2`?

Comment: I need to do mapping of car1 with other cars. so the order of id's should be the same in both the data frames. I apologize for using the word sorting.

Comment: Thanks, @mitoRibo. It works.